# No Accumulation Point sin(nx)

Tags: real-analysis

I hope this question is not too trivial - when I was solving a different problem, I somehow strived off and eventually conjectured this.

Let $(V, \| \cdot \|)$ be a normed space and let $r > 0$. Then the closed ball
$$ \overline{B_r(x)} = \{y \in V : \|y-x \| \leq r \} $$ is not compact in general.

This main problem can be found on stackexchange as I've just seen. However, I want to pose a different question that relates to this problem - namely a specific sequence that would prove the result. I'm looking for a good proof here. (I can see that the main result can be resolved easier.)

My proof showed that $r \sin(nx)$ does not have an accumulation point in the normed space $(\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}), \|\cdot \|_{\infty})$ with supremum norm. However, this wasn't as straightforward for me as I had expected. I had to do some work but could eventually prove that any subsequence of $r \sin(nx)$ does not converge pointwise. What's the best way to approach this particular sequence?

Comment: The accumulation point **restricted to $[0,1]$**, say, would be uniformly continuous. Is that possible?

Comment: That's an amazing proof, thank you! (To answer your question: No. The accumulation point is $0$ at $0$ and approximates $1$ at $x=\frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$ but that converges to $0$ for $n \to \infty$. To make "approximate" precise, one could use some $\varepsilon$'s but that's just dirty work.)

Comment: If the accumulation point were uniformly continuous restricted to $[0,1]$ then some subsequence (namely, the one convergent to the accumulation point) would be (uniformly) equicontinuous restricted to $[0,1]$, and its impossibility is pretty easy to check.